# Phpunit partial mock + proxy Entity

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I tried find solution to my issue but didn't find anything.

I use: **Symfony, Doctrine, PhpUnit**

I have one entity class InvoiceNumerator:

```
/**
 * InvoiceNumerator
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="invoice_numerator")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\InvoiceNumeratorRepository")
 */
class InvoiceNumerator
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="translatedFormat", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $translatedFormat;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="currentValue", type="integer", options={"default": 0})
     */
    private $currentValue = 0;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="current_number", type="string", length=64)
     */
    private $currentNumber = '';

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set translatedFormat
     *
     * @param string $translatedFormat
     *
     * @return InvoiceNumerator
     */
    public function setTranslatedFormat($translatedFormat)
    {
        $this->translatedFormat = $translatedFormat;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get translatedFormat
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTranslatedFormat()
    {
        return $this->translatedFormat;
    }

    /**
     * Set currentValue
     *
     * @param integer $currentValue
     *
     * @return InvoiceNumerator
     */
    public function setCurrentValue($currentValue)
    {
        $this->currentValue = $currentValue;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get currentValue
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCurrentValue()
    {
        return $this->currentValue;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCurrentNumber(): string
    {
        return $this->currentNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $currentNumber
     * @return InvoiceNumerator
     */
    public function setCurrentNumber(string $currentNumber): InvoiceNumerator
    {
        $this->currentNumber = $currentNumber;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

and I need in my tests to mock this class, but my setters should be left the same - no stubs - working code.
To mock this class, I made simple mock method:

```
public function getInvoiceNumerator()
{
    $invoiceNumerator = $this->createMock(InvoiceNumerator::class);

    $invoiceNumerator->method('getTranslatedFormat')
        ->willReturn('FS-CM/{n}/2018/01');

    $invoiceNumerator->method('getCurrentValue')
        ->willReturn('1');

    $invoiceNumerator->method('getCurrentNumber')
        ->willReturn('FS-CM/1/2018/01');

    return $invoiceNumerator;
}
```

but in this case my setters are not working.
I can also set values on new Entity object:

```
public function getInvoiceNumerator()
{
    $invoiceNumerator = new InvoiceNumerator();
    $invoiceNumerator->setTranslatedFormat('FS-CM/{n}/2018/01');
    $invoiceNumerator->setCurrentValue(1);
    $invoiceNumerator->setCurrentNumber('FS-CM/1/2018/01');

    return $invoiceNumerator;
}
```

In this case my setters working properly.

### Question:

Is there any better way to do this? What is the best practice?

Comment: Finally the issue was that I mocked getCurrentValue and despite I increment variable mock was the same. My bad. BTW. Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: You probably need to mock the database and some data instead of mocking models. I think that will work out better for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You almost have the answer in your question “Phpunit partial mock + proxy Entity”: there is a `createPartialMock()` method which you can use like this:

```
$invoiceNumerator = $this-> createPartialMock(
    InvoiceNumerator::class,
    ['nameOfMockedMethod1', 'nameOfMockedMethod2']
);
```

This method has been available in PHPUnit 5.5 and newer. If you are using an older version, you can use `setMethods()`, but have to call it on the result returned by `getMockBuilder()`, not on the object returned by `createMock()` (which is the reason of the error you got after trying the approach from the 1st answer):

```
$subject = $this->getMockBuilder(MyClass::class)
    ->setMethods(['method1', 'method2'])
    ->getMock();
```

However, please note that `createPartialMock()` does slightly more. For instance, it will automatically disable the original constructor – which is almost always what you want in your tests (and what you have to do explicitly when using `setMethods()`). See documentation for exact information.

Comment: Thanks BlueM for your help I commented original question and described what was the issue. This answer describe the best my question. I didn't know method createPartialMock.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you can set your mock to only mock specific methods:

```
 $invoiceNumerator = $this->getMockBuilder(InvoiceNumerator::class)
                      ->setMethods(["getTranslatedFormat","getCurrentValue", "getCurrentNumber"])
                      ->getMock();
```

according to [the documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html#test-doubles.mock-objects.tables.matchers)

> `setMethods(array $methods)` can be called on the Mock Builder object to specify the methods that are to be replaced with a configurable test double. The behavior of the other methods is not changed. If you call setMethods(null), then no methods will be replaced.

Update:

Since PHPUnit 8 the `setMethods` function has been deprecated and replaced with `onlyMethods` for methods that exist on the mocked class and `addMethods` for methods that don't yet exist on the mock class (e.g. they will be implemented in the future but you want to text their dependencies assuming they already exist).

Comment: When i call setMethods like you said I receive: Error : Call to undefined method Mock_InvoiceNumerator_6484a02c::setMethods(). phpUnit 4.5.2.

Comment: This version also didn't work -         $invoiceNumerator = $this->getMockBuilder(InvoiceNumerator::class)
            ->setMethods(["getTranslatedFormat","getCurrentValue", "getCurrentNumber"])
            ->getMock();

Comment: It should work on ~4 [according to the old docs](http://devdocs.io/phpunit~4/test-doubles#test-doubles.stubs.examples.StubTest2.php) what's the error in the second case?

Comment: Thanks apokryfos for your help(vote up) I commented original question and described what was the issue.